# Vidyo.IO sharing screen and monitors error

Tags: c#, wpf, vidyo

I use vidyo.IO for communication using the following code

```
    ConnectorPKG.Initialize(); 
var  _connector = new Connector(Handle, Connector.ConnectorViewStyle.ConnectorviewstyleDefault, 8, "all@VidyoClient", "VidyoClient.log", 0);
// This should be called on each window resizing.
_connector.ShowViewAt(Handle, 0, 0, Weidth, Height);
// Registering to events we want to handle.
_connector.RegisterLocalCameraEventListener(new LocalCameraListener(this));
_connector.RegisterLocalWindowShareEventListener(new LocalWindowShareListener(this));
_connector.RegisterLocalMicrophoneEventListener(new LocalMicropfoneListener(this));
_connector.RegisterLocalSpeakerEventListener(new LocalSpeakerListener(this));
_connector.RegisterParticipantEventListener(new ParticipantListener(this));
_connector.RegisterLocalMonitorEventListener(new LocalMonitorListener(this));
_connector.RegisterMessageEventListener(new ChatListener(this));
 _connector.DisableDebug();
```

then after joining a room I share window using code like this

```
var winToShare = LocalWindows.FirstOrDefault( );
                if (winToShare != null)
                { 
                    winToShare.IsSelected = true;
                    //SetSelectedLocalWindow(winToShare);
                    SharingInProgress = _connector.SelectLocalWindowShare(winToShare.Object);                      
                }
```

and same for monitors , Now I always get this error

```
can't share overconstrained frame interval
```

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you developing for? Seems like you may be building a mobile app using Xamarin and if that's the case, you will not be able to do window/app share. That feature is available only on desktop and web clients.

Comment: No wpf app for windows